# NEO4J nodes under a node filter by relationship

Tags: neo4j

How can we add a relationship to the query.

Say A-[C01]-B-[C02]-D and A-[C01]-B-[C03]-E

C01 C02 C03 are relationship codes I want to get output

B E

because I want only nodes that can be reached unbroken by C01 or C03

How can I get this result in Cypher?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to clarify, what you're asking for seems like a very simple case of matching. You may want to provide some more info, such as node labels and how you're matching to your start nodes, since without these we have to make things up for example code.

```
MATCH (a:Thing)
WHERE a.ID = 123
WITH a
MATCH (a)-[:C01|C03*]->(b:Thing)
RETURN b
```

The key here is specifying multiple relationship types to traverse, using * for multiplicity, so it will match on all nodes that can be reached by any chain of those relationships.